# Sirikit - Adding Siri custom intent to a framework

Tags: swift, ios-frameworks, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I've seen many articles which demonstrate : "How to add Siri extension to my app" and "Create shared framework to share code between apps & extension"

My questions and my need is exactly as mentioned into the title : Is it possible to add Siri custom intent to a framework (and not an app)? If yes, how?
So I can build an App using my framework containing all the intent possible to use.

For the moment, I've succeeded to configure and use a swiftui "Add to siri Button". The right intent is presented to me, well, I can tap on "Add to Siri". But then, the error:

> "The operation couldn't be completed. (WFActionError-Domain error1)"

appears when I try to use my shortcut inside the shortcut App

EDIT: The last idea I got is, the problem might occur because the app doesn't own the intent when I try to create my shortcut.
I mean, something dealing with the bundle ID, don't you think ?

Comment: I saw the same or a similar question yesterday or the day before yesterday.

Comment: It's definitely me, because I closed my question for some reason.

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817087/sirikit-error-donating-intent-is-not-supported-by-this-application

Comment: @stevekohls unfortunately, that is not what I'm looking for. This guy is sharing a framework between the app and the intent extension. More precisely, what I need is like an extension to my framework (not my app)
I want to create a project which the only thing to do, link my framework